# C# TabControl - is it possible to "disable" individual TabPages?

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

Is it somehow possible to disable one (or more) tabs of tab control? At some point I need to make user stay on the active tab and prevent him from leaving... I know I can disable the whole TabControl component, but that disables also all components on active tab...

I also tried to use the Selecting method of TabControl:

```
private void TabControl_Selecting(object sender, TabControlCancelEventArgs e) {           
    e.Cancel = PreventTabSwitch;
}
```

This works, prevents user from switching (if PreventTabSwitch==true), but since all tabs look active and just don't react it's confusing...

There is no Enabled property for individual tab pages, so I don't know what else to do...

Thanks a lot for in advance for all tips.

Comment: You could always combine it with changing the colour of the TabControls font to grey so that it looks a bit disabled.

Comment: Even assuming you used say the FlatTabControl and added a custom per-page "Enabled" property, you're still going to confuse users. If you really want to do this, either use the ErrorProvider component like Barry suggested, or pop up a message box when the user tries to switch tabs. Tabs are *inherently* confusing and disabled tabs, even more so. And likely to cause "UI widget rage" in certain of your users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, this is the only way to prevent a user from switching tabs.

I presume you are preventing them from leaving as validation on the form has failed?  Using the ErrorProvider component would provide some sort of visual cue that they need to do something before switching tabs.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar need once (I wanted the active tab to have different background color and some other stuff) and ended up creating new Controls that inherited from `TabControl` & `TabPage` where I used `OwnerDraw` to alter the look.

What you are doing is the right way to go according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/252t3cec.aspx) but it does suggest that another option is to hide/show the pages as needed.

Comment: Be careful with the hiding approach. `TabPage.Visible` has a bug where it does not hide the tab page - http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/94157/tabpage-visible-is-not-working

Comment: I had a small notion when I read it that I had encountered something that was weird with hiding TabPages. But can still store references to the pages elsewhere and remove/insert as needed.

Answer (score 0):

- *TabControl - Disable/Enable tab page* at 
  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/985b41c3-a1de-4744-8875-63262d4c2718/
- MSDN Search for "tabcontrol disabled tabpage" at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=tabcontrol+disabled+tabpage&ac=8

Answer (score 0):

The user cannot click on tabs to navigate, but they can use the two buttons ( Next , Back ). The user cannot continue to the next if the //conditions are no met

```
private int currentTab = 0;

private void frmOneTimeEntry_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tabMenu.Selecting += new TabControlCancelEventHandler(tabMenu_Selecting);
    }
private void tabMenu_Selecting(object sender, TabControlCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        tabMenu.SelectTab(currentTab);
    }
private void btnNextStep_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch(tabMenu.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                //if conditions met GoTo
            case 2:
                //if conditions met GoTo
            case n:
                //if conditions met GoTo
        {
        CanLeaveTab:
            currentTab++;
             tabMenu.SelectTab(tabMenu.SelectedIndex + 1);
            if (tabMenu.SelectedIndex == 3)
                btnNextStep.Enabled = false;
            if (btnBackStep.Enabled == false)
                btnBackStep.Enabled = true;

        CannotLeaveTab:
        ;

    }

    private void btnBackStep_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        currentTab--;
        tabMenu.SelectTab(tabMenu.SelectedIndex - 1);
        if (tabMenu.SelectedIndex == 0)
            btnBackStep.Enabled = false;
        if (btnNextStep.Enabled == false)
            btnNextStep.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cancel the change of a tab, you can use the Deselecting event. There you can cancel the change by setting property Cancel of the provided TabControlCancelEventArgs to true.